# Jenkins branch name merged to

Tags: git, jenkins, branch, git-branch

I am trying to access to the variable containing origin/develop:

[image: jenkins]

From the shell script in the config.
I know how to access the upstream branch with this:

> $GIT_BRANCH

How / Which variable I can use to access the downstream merged branch "orgin/develop"

Comment: Did you checkin the Environment Variable page for that build?

Comment: can you post your git plugin configuration for that job?